# Xpath node selection - how to select 2 different elements?

Tags: c#, select, xpath, html-agility-pack, nodes

I am trying this as selecting multiple nodes via HtmlAgilityPack but it fails. So, what I am trying to do is collecting `a` nodes and `li` nodes inside the breadcrumbs `div` element.

This is what I tried:

```
string srxPathOfCategory = "//div[@class='breadcrumbs']//li or //div[@class='breadcrumbs']//a";
var selectedNodes = myDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(srxPathOfCategory);
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: please post sample of html you are trying to select from. The exact html, not something you pull out of your head that you think is "close enough."

Comment: Actually it is not necessary. If you were experienced enough with Xpath you would know what to be used instead of "or" word. Also I found the solution edited message.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Put it as an answer, and mark it as such :)

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray moderators not liking it. I did it before and they deleted all of my posts :D I can delete the question but that time system does not like :d You can post as answer i will mark it.

Comment: I don't think the moderators would delete a valid question with a valid answer. If you've found the answer to your own question, please post it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution is

```
string srxPathOfCategory = "//div[@class='breadcrumbs']//li[@class='product'] | //div[@class='breadcrumbs']//a";
```

So for " or " you need to use " | "

Comment: Will this statement also treat OR as "additional" nodes? i.e. If I want to get tr[1]. [2], and tr[last()]. Would the `|` work, is there another parameter needed, or do they all need to be separate.